# Add git alias with number in bash_profile not working

Tags: bash, git, terminal

I add `alias gcl1 ='git clone --depth 1'` in `bash_profile` but when i run `source ~/.bash_profile`,i get error `.bash_profile:43: git clone --depth 1 not found`

but `alias gcd='git checkout dev'` works and i guess it's because of the number

How to fix this error?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the space after the alias name "gcl1".

```
alias gcl1='git clone --depth 1'
```

not:

```
alias gcl1 ='git clone --depth 1'
```